# itemize environment giving this error for unclear reason: Something's wrong, perhaps a missing \item( its happening on line 11)

Tags: latex

I am using itemize, not missing an `\item` (to my knowledge) and there isn't any extra text without an `item` that I know of. I'm pretty sure I'm using itemize correctly because I've used it in the same way for other 'LaTeX' files before with no issue. I'm really confused.

Also, when I removed the code that had the error, it told me that another section of code that was fine before now had the same error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item recombinant
    \item Deoxyribose vs Ribose: Only one difference
    \item Nitrogen Bases in DNA
    \begin{itemize}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Purines, 2 rings
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Adenine
                \item Guanine
           \end{itemize}{}
        \end{itemize}{}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Pyrimidines, 1 ring
            \begin{itemize}
                \item T
                \item C
            \end{itemize}{}
        \end{itemize}{}
    \end{itemize}{}
    \item[Nitrogen bases = Steps of ladder]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item phosphate group
        \item deoxyribose sugar(connected to nitrogen base)
    \end{itemize}{}
\end{itemize}{}
\end{document}{}
```

Comment: This is a LaTeX question, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `\item`. In your second level itemization, you immediately try to start a third level itemization without having an item before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item recombinant
    \item Deoxyribose vs Ribose: Only one difference
    \item Nitrogen Bases in DNA
    \begin{itemize}
       \item \begin{itemize}
            \item Purines, 2 rings
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Adenine
                \item Guanine
           \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Pyrimidines, 1 ring
            \begin{itemize}
                \item T
                \item C
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \item[Nitrogen bases = Steps of ladder]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item phosphate group
        \item deoxyribose sugar(connected to nitrogen base)
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```